# de broglie thesis

Tags: waves, wavelength

Quoting Thesis (1924) "Propagation is, therefore, analogous to a liquid wave in a channel closed
on itself but of variable depth."
What is meaning of depth here?

edit as new image

[image]

Comment: Water in a channel has a depth, like “6 feet deep here, 8 feet deep there”.

Comment: Unless you are a historian of physics, reading original papers is not necessarily the best way to learn a subject. We have had a century to improve QM pedagogy.

Comment: @Ghoster ty but is the image correct representation of a wave in closed channel like a pipe or conduit or would it be a longitudinal wave? image is not part of thesis. what would depth mean in longitudinal wave?

Comment: @Ghoster was reading an article from 2014.

Comment: The images don’t look like water waves in a channel to me. They look like sound waves in an organ pipe.

Comment: @Ghoster yeah, that's just an analogous image used by me. although energy quantification can be easily understood by means of amplitude of wave in transverse wave. why did de Broglie used the liquid wave in closed channel analogy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148847/discussion-between-sage-and-ghoster).